# Can I use a Wolf or a Dire-Wolf as a Warlock familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, warlock, familiars

I'm new at D&D and I want to create a Drow, Rogue-Warlock (First Rogue and later Warlock) but I want to have a Dire-Wolf as a familiar but I don't know if it's possible. I want it for the background I'm building for my character.

I saw in the Appendix D of the Player's Handbook the Dire Wolf and Wolf that's why I was wondering, if I can, that would fit excellent in my character's background.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By the rules, no. The Pact of the Chain says:

> You learn the *find familiar* spell and can cast it as a ritual. The spell doesn't count against your number of spells known.
>
> When you cast the spell, you can choose one of the normal forms for your familiar or one of the following special forms: imp, pseudodragon, quasit, or sprite.

And the *find familiar* spell says:

> You gain the service of a familiar, a spirit that takes an animal form you choose: bat, cat, crab, frog (toad), hawk, lizard, octopus, owl, poisonous snake, fish (quipper), rat, raven, sea horse, spider, or weasel.

The list of which creatures you can use as a familiar is highly specific, and doesn't include either the Wolf or the Dire Wolf.

That said, some of the options available to a Pact of the Chain warlock are quite a bit more powerful than a Wolf. The Imp and the Quasit are both CR 1 to a Wolf's CR 1/4, with spellcasting abilities to boot, so a generous DM might be willing to stretch a point and let you use a Wolf instead, particularly if it's appropriate for a character. I suspect a Dire Wolf is probably out of the question, though.

There is another potential alternative: If you took 3 levels of Ranger, you could get an Animal Companion, for which a Wolf is an option. Depending on your character, a Ranger might fit as a substitute for Rogue. A character for whom a Wolf familiar makes sense sounds a bit Ranger-ish to me. Only you know what you want your character to be, both mechanically and thematically, so I can't really advise you too much here.

Answer (score -4):

At the end of the day, it's entirely up to your DM.  If he let's you, fine.  If he doesn't, that should be fine too.  It might help if you did a couple of things to prepare before you ask:

1. Find an example in literature where a rogue/warlock has a familiar that is a Dire Wolf.
2. Provide a compelling reason why this is necessary (because it would be awesome is usually not good enough).
3. Bring 2 batches of homemade cookies to your next game (one for only him and one for the party).

One of the things to remember about 5th Edition is that the goal of the system is to simplify things.  3.5 made characters waaaay to powerful and with all of the prestige stuff, the game grew away from the original idea of role-playing and became a video game like hack and slash roll-playing disaster.